# Customize display of an enumeration class

Tags: matlab, oop, enums, string-formatting, overriding

I'd like to customize the display of an enumeration class using `matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay`.

If I have a regular (non-enumeration) class such as the following:

```
classdef test < handle & matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay
    properties
       value
    end
    methods
        function obj = test(value)
           obj.value = value;
        end
    end
    methods (Access = protected)
    function displayScalarObject(obj)
        disp(['hello ', num2str(obj.value)])
    end
    end
end
```

then everything works fine - for example,

```
>> a = test(1)
a = 
hello 1
```

But if I have an enumeration class such as the following (note the addition of the `enumeration` block):

```
classdef test < handle & matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay
    properties
       value
    end
    methods
        function obj = test(value)
           obj.value = value;
        end
    end
    methods (Access = protected)
    function displayScalarObject(obj)
        disp(['hello ', num2str(obj.value)])
    end
    end
    enumeration
        enum1(1)
    end
end
```

then the display is not customized - for example,

```
>> a = test.enum1
a = 
    enum1
```

Using the debugger, I can see that my `displayScalarObject` method is never called. Implementing other methods of `matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay` such as `displayNonScalarObject` and so on doesn't seem to help - these never get called either.

What's going on? Do `disp` and `display` work differently for enumeration classes, in such a way that anything that's overridden by `matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay` just gets ignored?

Is there a way to get a customized display with `matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay`, but using an enumeration class?

PS I am able to directly overload `disp` and/or `display` on an enumeration class that does not inherit from `matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay`, and this works fine. But I'm looking to use `matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay` if possible.

Comment: It looks like a limitation, but I don't think it's an unreasonable one. Enumerations are supposed to represent entities with *descriptive names* (as opposed to using magic numbers or hardcoded strings). IMO the name of an enum should be descriptive enough on its own that one doesn't need to overload `disp` (either directly or indirectly with `matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay`). I realize there is an inconsistency here seeing that overloading `disp` works while `matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay` doesn't, I still argue that one shouldn't need to do this either way..

Comment: @Amro I know what you're saying, and for a scalar I'd agree. But my question above is actually a simplification of my real need - I have an enumeration class that would benefit from a custom display when I have an array of values (I want to show a grid containing a symbol for each element of the array, rather than have it say "2x4 array of myClass").

Comment: I think the default way of displaying enum arrays is similar to what you want: `repmat(test.enum1,[2 4])` will display a grid of symbols (the uncustomized ones). If that doesn't fit your requirements, I'm afraid you'll have to manually override `disp` and write code to handle scalar vs. array cases (basically reimplement the output of CustomDisplay yourself).. Anyway you should submit a bug report to MathWorks to let them know, at least they will confirm it's either a bug or an undocumented limitation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question in case anyone else is interested.

The question was asked with reference to MATLAB R2014a. In R2014b, an additional note has been added to the documentation for `matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay`, making it explicit that it is not possible to use `matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay` to derive a custom display for enumeration classes, and suggesting that the best approach is to overload `disp`.